# usage of echo in the script

Tags: shell, tcsh

I tried to use a copied script, which includes the following command

```
echo "rc  $2" > $WORKDIR/out.dat
```

I can guess it tries to output some contents to file out.dat. But what does "rc $2" mean?

It also includes

```
echo "PWD" >> $WORKDIR/env.txt
```

Why it uses >> here instead of >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"rc" means nothing here and neither does "PWD". They are just strings. They presumably mean something in out.dat and env.txt, though. The "$2" is a reference to the second arg used to call the script.

`>>` means append to a file rather than overwriting it like `>` will do.

Answer (score 0):

`$2` is the 2nd incoming var when the script is executed.

example:

```
./script.sh foo bar   # $2 would be bar
```

`>>` means append to file instead of overwrite file entirely.